# How to change the index of some value in Ext js combobox

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs3

I have a combobox gets the list of values  from serverside. When I add a new
value in db ,it will reflect at the last index of the combobox.My requirement is
for a given value I want to change the index to zero.

For example if I added x and y as new values , now I want to change the
index of x to zero.

My combobox code:

```
{
    xtype : 'combo',
    //typeAhead : true,
    triggerAction : 'all',
    name : 'agreementTypeCombo',
    id : 'agreementTypeCombo',
    //hiddenName : 'agreementTypeCombo',
    editable : false,
    mode : 'local',
    store : new Ext.data.JsonStore({

        fields : [{
                    name : 'id',
                    mapping : 'id'
                }, {
                    name : 'label',
                    mapping : 'label'
                }

        ],
        idProperty : 'id',
        data :  MD_updateOpportunityMasterDataVO.agreementTypeList
    }),
    valueField : 'id',
    displayField : 'label',
    //emptyText : CONST_NOT_AVAILABLE,
    fieldLabel : 'Agreement Type',
        labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;',
    helpText : getFieldTip(MODULE_NAME,CATEGORY_SALES_SUMMARY,'Agreement Type'),
    //allowBlank : false,
    anchor : '95%',
    value : opportunityVO.agreementTypeId
}
```

Comment: Use the store `insert` to specify the position.

Comment: you can add extra id field to each record and then sort all the records in callback function of store load.

Comment: for what exactly you want this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you add it locally use

```
store.insert(0, newItem);
```

If you add it on server and then reload then the server must return the combo store records in the required order.